# awk loop with more instances and space

Tags: awk

this is my text:

```
haeasdf apple sdfgsdg 
asdfa orange sdfg sfgs
sdfg s apple sgdfgsg
sg sdfg orange sfgsfg 
sdfg orange sgsfgsdg
...
```

so I use `awk` to replace the text to

```
awk {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/apple/){sub(/apple/,"apple ++count",$i)}}} 1;


haeasdf apple1 sdfgsdg 
asdfa orange sdfg sfgs
sdfg s apple2 sgdfgsg
sg sdfg orange sfgsfg 
sdfg orange sgsfgsdg
...
```

Do I have to run another time for `orange` as I failed to combine then if change `i` to `j` do it like `{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/apple/){sub(/apple/,"apple ++count",$i)}}} 1; {for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){if($j~/orange/){sub(/orange/,"orange ++count",$j)}}} 1;`

**[2]** I found I am unable use this command
`awk {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/apple[[:space:]]banana/){sub(/apple[[:space:]]banana/,"apple ++count",$i)}}} 1;` or `awk {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/apple banana/){sub(/apple banana/,"apple ++count",$i)}}} 1;` if there is a space

```
some words here apple banana some words here 
some words here orange some words here
some words here apple banana some words here
some words here orange some words here
some words here orange some words here
...
```

I wanted to replace `apple banana` to be `apple`. So the output like below

```
some words here apple1 some words here 
some words here orange some words here
some words here apple2 some words here
some words here orange some words here
some words here orange some words here
...
```

Comment: not sure if I understood your question well, does `awk '{print $0, ++a[$0]}' file` solve your problem?

Comment: @Sundeep thanks, sorry I didn't make it question properly.

Comment: @olo, so for `oragne` also you want to make it like `orange1,oragne2` and so on... could you please confirm the same once?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes, I'd like to have orange to be `orange1,oragne2...` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. One could mention all string values in `awk` variable named `str` with comma separated and those values will be written in output with their count occurrences in output.

```
awk -v str="apple,orange" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(str,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    numFound[arr[i]]
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i in numFound){ $i=$i "" ++count[$i] }
  }
}
1' Input_file
```

One liner form of solution as per OP's need in comments:

`awk -v str="apple,orange" 'BEGIN{num=split(str,arr,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){numFound[arr[i]]}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in numFound){$i=$i "" ++count[$i]}}}1' Input_file`

---

---

***EDIT1:*** As per OP's 2nd samples try following.

```
awk -v str="apple,orange" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(str,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    numFound[arr[i]]
  }
}
{
  gsub(/apple banana/,"apple")
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i in numFound){ $i=$i "" ++count[$i] }
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, having `syntax error`

Comment: @olo, this has worked fine for me and tested it well, could you please double check its copied correctly(I just re-ran it) and All is Well with it, kindly do re-run it by copying it again and let me know then, cheers.

Comment: still having errors. even converted it to one line `awk -v str="apple,orange" 'BEGIN{num=split(str,arr,",") for(i=1;i<=num;i++){numFound[arr[i]] } } {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in numFound){ $i=$i "" ++count[$i] } } } 1' inFile`

Comment: @olo, in one liner try `awk -v str="apple,orange" 'BEGIN{num=split(str,arr,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){numFound[arr[i]]}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in numFound){$i=$i "" ++count[$i]}}}1' Input_file` and let me know then?

Comment: Could you please advise if `sdfg s apple banana sgdfgsg` to be `sdfg s apple1 sgdfgsg` like asked in the question. How to include the space? `"apple banana, orange" ` not working

Comment: @olo, Sorry I didn't get it, could you please explain logic of getting your expected output here?

Comment: sorry, like this text `some words apple banana some words <linebreak>
some words apple some words <linebreak>
some words apple banana some words <linebreak>
...` to change `apple banana` to be `apple 1, apple 2...` oh, I can't make line break here

Comment: @olo, I am really sorry, I am not getting what's the logic of removing words here? Kindly explain it please and will fix my solution then. You want to remove all other words which are NOT matched?

Comment: @olo, Could you please try following, `awk -v str="apple,orange" 'BEGIN{num=split(str,arr,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){numFound[arr[i]]}} {gsub(/apple banana/,"apple");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in numFound){$i=$i "" ++count[$i]}}}1'  Input_file` and let me know then?